# Select rows from two matrices iteratively and perform function in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix, distance

So I have a rather complex (at least for me) problem in R.

I want to calculate distances between two pair of distributions, for nearly 10k pairs.

I have a `distance` function from package `philentropy`, which takes two vectors `x` `y` and calculates the distance between them such as:

```
d <- distance(x, y, method="desired_method")
```

Another option is to create a matrix with each row representing a distribution, so that the function will calculate all pairwise distances among all distributions in the matrix:

```
d <- distance(x, method="desired_method")
```

I have two correlation matrices `a` and `b` with nearly 10k rows each, corresponding to 10k correlation distributions. Both matrices have the same number of rows, and my goal is to contrast first row of matrix `a` with first row of matrix `b`, second `a` row with second `b` row and so on, iteratively.

I can select each desired rows and perform the first `distance` usage, or I can merge the two matrices with `rbind` and perform all pairwise distances with second `distance` usage.

The problem is, with first approach, I do not know how to generate a `for` loop to iteratively get the nth row of each matrix, and perform `distance` calculation, while storing the result in a vector.

Additionally, if I perform the second option, I do not want to get all pairwise distances, but just distances corresponding to:

```
d[i,i+nrow(a)]
```

And doing so iteratively to generate a corresponding vector of `nrow(a)` values.

Any help?

Comment: To get the nth row of a matrix named ‘mat’, you use the syntax:   mat[n,]

Comment: I don't see a *y* argument in [`philentropy::distance`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/philentropy/versions/0.3.0/topics/distance).

Answer (score 0):

If you have two matrices, mat_x and mat_y, each with the same number of rows, then the for loop would be:

```
answer <- vector(mode = 'numeric', length = 10000L)

for (i in 1:10000){
  answer[[i]] <- distance(mat_x[i,], mat_y[i,], method="desired_method")
}
```